# In Firefox the mousemove event is triggered while scrolling with the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I have a `mousemove` event on a scrollable div. Firefox is the only major browser that fires the `mousemove` event while I am dragging the scroll slider. Do you know a way to get rid of that?

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="reporter1"></div>
<div id="reporter2"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#outer").on("scroll", function (event) {
    $("#reporter1").text("scroll");
});

$("#outer").on("mousemove", function (event) {
    $("#reporter2").text("mousemove");
});

setInterval(function () {
    $("#reporter1").text("");
    $("#reporter2").text("");
}, 500);
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurumusch/6DqRU/13/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) event handler, and a simple timer :

```
var timer;
rebind();

$('#outer').on('scroll', function(){
     clearTimeout(timer);
     $('#outer').off('mousemove');
     timer = setTimeout(rebind, 500);
});

function rebind() {
     $('#outer').on('mousemove',function() {
             $("#reporter2").text("mousemove");
     });
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that because a) the handlers are in two different modules so reregistering will be difficult and b) timeouts are a pain in unittests

Comment: Okay, it was just a workaround. The idea is that you unbind the mousemove when a scroll is triggered. After the end of this scroll, you rebind the whole thing. And, FYI, Chrome also trigger a mousemove when you scroll.

Comment: Chrome "29.0.1547.62 m" does trigger a mousemove when clicking the scroll up/down buttons or using the mouse wheel. It does not trigger mousemove when moving the slider. But my problem occurs in firefox.